# VBA Copy SQL Table without Header

Tags: vba, excel

I'm try to copy data from SQl-Server to Excel, but the result is include with headers. I want result without headers. Here my code :

```
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\User;Database=User;Uid=User;Pwd=User;"
If Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "SC" Then
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '2' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW'"
ElseIf Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "MC" Then
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '3' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW'" 'and startby is Null"
ElseIf Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "EV" Then
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '5' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW' and pos_no like 'EN5%'"
End If

Connection.Open ConnectionString
rs.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(rs, Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2))
QT.Refresh:    rs.Close:    QT.Delete:    Connection.Close
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just delete the header row after? Or use `GetRows` property of the recordset

Comment: Try `ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\User;Database=User;Uid=User;Pwd=User;HDR=No"`

Comment: @UGP ... using "HDR" in SQL recordset doesn't make any change...

Comment: @Tom Can u give me example how to use `GetRows`. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Use CopyFromRecordset!

```
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\User;Database=User;Uid=User;Pwd=User;"
If Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "SC" Then
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '2' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW'"
ElseIf Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "MC" Then
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '3' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW'" 'and startby is Null"
ElseIf Sheets("Menu").Cells(4, 4) = "EV" Then
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [MVS].[dbo].[trpos_process] where fc = '5' and process = 'ASSEMBLY' and status = 'NEW' and pos_no like 'EN5%'"
End If

Connection.Open ConnectionString
rs.Open Sql, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Range("b2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close:    QT.Delete:    Connection.Close
```

Comment: I get error when Using CopyFromRecordset (Automation Error)